# How to free space on server when pg_wal of Postgresql-12 dramatically increase size?

Tags: postgresql-12

I am facing problem server nearly full space because of Postgresql. I went through several hours still could not find solution to free space on server, I am using Postgresql v12 on Centos7 I don't know what wrong to my configuration the directory /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_wal size 210GB.
Thank in advance.

Comment: What are the values of `wal_level`, `archive_mode`,  `max_wal_size`, `min_wal_size` and `wal_keep_segments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable archiving by using **archive_command**  and place all logs in some other directory with compressed format. Please have a look on below link for more on WAL archiving.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/continuous-archiving.html

Comment: you need to put below command in config and take restart as per you OS. destination would be where you have space. So it'll release space from **/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_wal**

`archive_command = 'cp %p /mnt/server/archivedir/%f'`  **# Unix**
`archive_command = 'copy "%p" "C:\\server\\archivedir\\%f"'`  **# Windows**

Comment: so current pag_wal size too big no way to remove file for release some space?  because server on cloud.

Comment: WAL files contain individual statements that modify tables so if you throw some older WALs out, then the recovery process will fail (it will not silently skip missing WAL files) because the state of the database cannot be restored reliably. You can move the WAL files to some other location without upsetting the WAL process but then you'd have to make all WAL files available again from a single location if you ever need to recover your database from some point in the past;

Comment: you can use **pg_archivecleanup** utility to clean WAL files.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/pgarchivecleanup.html

Comment: I fixed base on @ROHIT KHURANA  postgresql.org/docs/9.5/pgarchivecleanup.html  (my version 12)
And add little bit more on this: http://support.info2soft.com/service/public.pl?Action=PublicFAQZoom;ItemID=552;ZoomBackLink=Action%3DPublicFAQSearch%3BSubaction%3DSearch%3BSortBy%3DLanguage%3BOrder%3DDown%3BStartHit%3D1;